# Does Spring Security Saml 2.0 support Assertion Level Encryption and AES-256 as Encryption Algorithm?

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I am relatively new to SSO. There are two requirements (see title) I'd like to check against my Spring Framework environment but I am not sure how to get the answers. It seems like the docs also don't provide a direct answer to this.

Any input would be appreciated on how to determine what is supported or not in this SAML implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spring SAML is able to receive SAML messages encrypted using AES-256 (http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc) by default. But it is not possible to configure Spring SAML to encrypt messages sent to IDP.